# how does android.net.Uri work

Tags: android, uri, video-on-demand

now I'm developing an android Video on Demand or Audio on Demand Player, I notice there's a function in package android.net.Uri, part of my code of play the video or audio is like this:

Play Audio part:

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://.../MJ.mp3"));
mPlayer.setLooping(true);
mPlayer.start();
```

Play Video Part:

```
VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
String vidAddress = "https://.../ABC.mp4";
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
vidView.start();
```

I'm wondering does this satisfy the video or audio on demand request? In an other word, when I play the audio or video using the URI function, does it work like Youtube, which downloads just part of the video and plays the video, or download the whole file first then play it?

Comment: Seems the question is not 'how does android.net.Uri work', but 'how MediaPlayer work if Uri provided'.

Comment: @sandrstar I'm confused with this now, because I don't know which part is used for buffering, URI or MediaPlayer.

Comment: @sandrstar if you know how to setup a fully controlled video streaming server and how to play the streaming video, that will be very helpful

Comment: Not an expert in video play. Uri is just an address string, it doesn't have any additional function (e.g. like buffering). Buffer or not depends on Media Player.